# SenchaTouch2 - NestedList - Title "cut off"

Tags: sencha-touch-2

I've created a NestedList with some data inside .. everything works as expected. But there is one weird thing..

The last 2 characters of the title are always replaced with dots - I don't know why ...

Any explanations?

Comment: No matter the length of the title ? And also add your code so we can help you.

Comment: Yes, no matter the length. But it seams to be a bug that only occurs in chrome(desktop).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?228621-Short-titles-in-title-bar-also-gets-clipped-with-text-ellipsis it](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?228621-Short-titles-in-title-bar-also-gets-clipped-with-text-ellipsis) it fixed in 2.1.0-b2

As far as I judge it is CSS issue, because on the real device (iPhone test) no such quirks

Cheers, Oleg

Comment: This is definately a bug, I noticed it first on the 2.1 release. For now you can overide this by adding this class:
.x-title {
text-overflow:none !important;
}

Comment: Yes, it seams to be a bug, but it only occurs in chrome (desktop) (with my application). In Safari on the iPhone everything works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

This can be fixed with this solution, which only shows dots when necessary:

```
.x-title .x-innerhtml:after {
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    width: .3em; /* equal to the amount of padding on the element */
}
```