# Title of the Toolbar gets cut when too long text in it

Tags: sencha-touch-2

Title of the Toolbar gets cut when too long text in it, see the picture:

[image]

Here is the code:

```
launch: function () {

        var myTabPanel = Ext.create('Ext.Toolbar', {
        fullscreen: true,
        title: {
            title: 'BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA',
            style: {
                'text-align': 'left'
            }
        },
        docked: 'top',
        defaults: {
            iconMask: true,
            ui: 'plain'
        }
    });

    [...]

    myTabPanel.add([ start, ...]);
```

The code for 'start':

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.Start',     {
    extend: 'Ext.Button',
    config: {
        html: 'Start',
        iconCls: 'home'
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No worry!

It's a Chrome issue and also bug registered for Sencha to rectify it. It will soon be fixed in the upcoming releases.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug, read this post and view my comment for a temporary fix: [SenchaTouch2 - NestedList - Title "cut off"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11796915/senchatouch2-nestedlist-title-cut-off)